# Getting uuids of references with Get filtering

Tags: graphql, weaviate

I understand one can get the uuid of an object using .with_additional([id]).
Let say now, I request references as well for example:

```
where_filter = {
  "path": ["name"],
  "operator": "Equal",
  "valueText": "whatever"
}


(client.query.get("Node", ['name', 'hasChildren{... on Node{name}}'])
    .with_where(where_filter)
    .with_additional(['id'])
    .do())
```

the .with_additional applies only to the parent node and you would not get uuids of "hasChildren" references, I tried to play by replacing Node{name} with Node{id} but no chance. Is there any way I can get the uuids of the references as well.

Now I have notice that using the object endpoint will actually return the references with beacons, however, you cant do any filtering with the endpoint directly. There is kind of a hole here.

This one is tricky, either I can nicely filter what I want with graphql but then have to make extra query to get uuids, or I can get uuids with the endpoint but have to implement some extra logic filtering at application level. I feel like I must be wrong, its a massive hole here.